# which string matching algorithm is used in stl?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, stl, stdstring

Which is used as the string matching algorithm in c++ stl std::string.find()?
I have been studying about string matching algorithms and want to know which one has been used by stl c++.

Comment: Are you talking about the historical STL, or the STL part of the C++ spec? The first is quite old; the second will depend on the implementation.

Comment: the second one,stl part of  c++.

Comment: If you're hoping for Boyer-Moore and the like, you're out of luck until the Library Fundamentals TS is adopted (and implemented).

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569664/string-search-algorithm-used-by-stringfind-c

Answer (score 3):

The STL does not specify implementations, but rather interfaces and constraints, including complexity constraints.

So, for example, it won't say that `std::map` has to be a red-black tree, but it does specify that search is worst-case logarithmic; if you read the complexity constraints, you can see it pretty-much has to be a balanced tree.

If you look at [`str::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)`s complexity, you can see "Unspecified, but generally up to linear in length()-pos times the length of the sequence to match (worst case).", so it basically allows (but does not specify) the naive algorithm.

Implementations of the family to which you're referring are in [this boost library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/algorithm/doc/html/algorithm/Searching.html), though.

Answer (score 3):

The string matching algorithm of std::string.find() is not specified by the starndard and is implementation-dependent. You can read the source code of an implementation to find which one is used.

For GCC, you may want to see the file [basic_string.tcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/libstdc++/api/a00771_source.html). The find() part in that file is:

```
00736   template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits, typename _Alloc>
00737     typename basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type
00738     basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::
00739     find(const _CharT* __s, size_type __pos, size_type __n) const
00740     {
00741       __glibcxx_requires_string_len(__s, __n);
00742       const size_type __size = this->size();
00743       const _CharT* __data = _M_data();
00744 
00745       if (__n == 0)
00746     return __pos <= __size ? __pos : npos;
00747 
00748       if (__n <= __size)
00749     {
00750       for (; __pos <= __size - __n; ++__pos)
00751         if (traits_type::eq(__data[__pos], __s[0])
00752         && traits_type::compare(__data + __pos + 1,
00753                     __s + 1, __n - 1) == 0)
00754           return __pos;
00755     }
00756       return npos;
00757     }
```

Answer (score -1):

All standard algorithms that have word `find` in their names except methods of associative containers use sequential search.

Comment: But for string search algorithms, there are are wildly-different ways of doing sequential search. when finding y in x, it will probably be sequential in each of x and y, but will it be sequential in y for each iteration of sequential traversal in x?

Comment: @Ami Tavory AFAIK there were proposals to use other search methods for strings. But always they were named differently and were considered as new separate algorithms.